# TSQL Query count with multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that is structured like so:

```
Account, Tag
------------
123, dog
123, owl
456, pig
456, goat
678, dog
789, owl
```

I need to create a statement that will return the following data:

Tag name with the total number of account it's on:

```
Dog 2
owl 2
pig 1
goat 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select Tag, count(*)
from table
group by Tag
```

Comment: How would I include another column in there as well? I have one more called total clicks so I need to add up all the clicks that each keyword has in total

Comment: @SBB add `, SUM(clicks)` to the select list